# unknown attribute: 1 when sending collection of records to controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Through javascript, users can add multiple models in a form. So there could be multiple input fields like below:

```
<div>
  <%= text_field_tag 'lead[1][some_value]' %>
  <%= text_field_tag 'lead[1][some_other_value]' %>
</div>
<div>
  <%= text_field_tag 'lead[2][some_value]' %>
  <%= text_field_tag 'lead[2][some_other_value]' %>
</div>
```

Then when form is submitted, the following params hash is sent:

```
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"1gkbq5T5cqxrPGND+1eS6oqc4Qv08oI7ADajY1GFw4g=",     
"lead"=> {
    "1"=>{"some_value"=>"fgdfgf", "some_other_value"=>"fgdfgf"}, 
    "2"=>{"some_value"=>"dfgfdggfh", "some_other_value"=>"dfgfdgfh"},  
    "3"=>{"some_value"=>"gdfghgfh", "some_other_value"=>"dfdgdfgfgh" }
}, 
"commit"=>"Create Lead"}
```

This is exactly what I want so I could do the following in the controller:

```
params[:lead].values.each do |lead|
    Lead.create(lead)
end
```

Unfortunately Rails doesn't get to the controller action. It raises an exception:

```
ActiveRecord::UnknownAttributeError - unknown attribute: 1:
  activerecord (4.1.5) lib/active_record/attribute_assignment.rb:50:in `rescue in _assign_attribute'
  activerecord (4.1.5) lib/active_record/attribute_assignment.rb:45:in `_assign_attribute'
  activerecord (4.1.5) lib/active_record/attribute_assignment.rb:56:in `block in assign_nested_parameter_attributes'
  activerecord (4.1.5) lib/active_record/attribute_assignment.rb:56:in `each'
  activerecord (4.1.5) lib/active_record/attribute_assignment.rb:56:in `assign_nested_parameter_attributes'
  activerecord (4.1.5) lib/active_record/attribute_assignment.rb:36:in `assign_attributes'
  activerecord (4.1.5) lib/active_record/core.rb:455:in `init_attributes'
  activerecord (4.1.5) lib/active_record/core.rb:198:in `initialize'
  activerecord (4.1.5) lib/active_record/inheritance.rb:30:in `new'
  activerecord (4.1.5) lib/active_record/inheritance.rb:30:in `new'
  cancancan (1.9.2) lib/cancan/controller_resource.rb:85:in `build_resource'
  cancancan (1.9.2) lib/cancan/controller_resource.rb:66:in `load_resource_instance'
  cancancan (1.9.2) lib/cancan/controller_resource.rb:32:in `load_resource'
  cancancan (1.9.2) lib/cancan/controller_resource.rb:25:in `load_and_authorize_resource'
```

Error seems to be coming from cancancan gem. It seems to think 1 is intended as an attribute, but I intend it to be an index in the collection. How can I make cancancan aware of this?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, I had to skip the load and authorization check in the controller. I was forced to do the following:

```
load_and_authorize_resource except: [:create]
skip_authorization_check only: [:create]
```